# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Tags: visual-studio, path, environment-variables

While installing python package I get the following error even though I have latest `Microsoft Visual Studio BuildTools` installed.

```
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

I have added all possible paths to Path variables as well

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Python Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild
```

Answer (score 0):

- Installing fulll `vs_BuildTools` solved it for me . For details follow
  https://www.scivision.dev/python-windows-visual-c-14-required
- Note `MSVC vXXX - VS YYYY C++ x64/x86 build tools` version and `Windows 10 SDK` versions must match
- Quick solutions like instaling `vc_redist.x64` or `VC_redist.x86` didn't
  solve it for me.
- Nothing needs to be added to environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Answer
If your vscode is supported in 32 bit version, it raises when you start install some packages. I recommended you to install 64  bit vscode if you are using windows 10.